# Here Maps iOS Build Failing

Tags: flutter, here-api, heremaps, heremaps-ios-sdk, here-ios

```
[!] Unable to install vendored xcframework `heresdk` for Pod `here_sdk`, because it contains both static and dynamic frameworks.

    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:1182:in `block (2 levels) in validate_xcframeworks'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:1161:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:1161:in `block in validate_xcframeworks'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:1160:in `each_value'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:1160:in `validate_xcframeworks'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:67:in `block in install!'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:149:in `message'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:40:in `install!'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:115:in `block in install_pod_targets'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:112:in `map'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:112:in `install_pod_targets'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/single_pods_project_generator.rb:32:in `block in install_all_pod_targets'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:149:in `message'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/single_pods_project_generator.rb:31:in `install_all_pod_targets'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/single_pods_project_generator.rb:19:in `generate!'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:314:in `block in create_and_save_projects'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:309:in `create_and_save_projects'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:301:in `generate_pods_project'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:180:in `integrate'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:167:in `install!'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

We are unsure of how to start debugging this issue running the latest here_sdk 4.10.4.0

Reproduced with the `hello_map_app` in addition to our app. [hello_map_app](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/explore/flutter/hello_map_app) on GH.

Full build logs: [build-log.txt](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/files/8239399/2.txt)

Comment: I would suggest to contact HERE support, if you haven't done so. It may be a problem with the local setup. It is worth to try if this happens also with earlier or newer versions. 4.10.5 is already out and it brought some major improvements.

Comment: did you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have missed some of the setup steps. Please follow below steps,which explain how we can integrate with here sdk.

Integrate the HERE SDK
On developer.here.com you can find the latest release artifacts including the HERE SDK framework to include in your application (named xx.yy.zz.release_date).

Copy the heresdk.xcframework folder to your app's root folder. Note that this folder contains more files, including a Info.plist file and two folders (ios-arm64, ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator).

In Xcode, open the General settings of the App target and add the heresdk.xcframework to the Frameworks, libraries, and embedded content section (Click "+", then "Add other..." -> "Add files...").

Set Your HERE Credentials
When using the HERE SDK, your application must be authe

Initialize the HERE SDK
The HERE SDK is not initialized automatically any longer. Instead, you can now freely decide at which point in time the HERE SDK should be initialized. Initialization happens synchronously on the main thread and takes around 100 ms.

In order to initialize the HERE SDK, execute the following method before you want to use the HERE SDK:

private func initializeHERESDK() {
// Set your credentials for the HERE SDK.
let accessKeyID = "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
let accessKeySecret = "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET"
let options = SDKOptions(accessKeyId: accessKeyID, accessKeySecret: accessKeySecret)
do {
try SDKNativeEngine.makeSharedInstance(options: options)
} catch let engineInstantiationError {
fatalError("Failed to initialize the HERE SDK. Cause: (engineInstantiationError)")
}
}

Add the Map View
Now that we have the SDK integrated into the project and added the required credentials, we can add a new MapView instance.

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

```
// Initialize MapView without a storyboard.
mapView = MapView(frame: view.bounds)
view.addSubview(mapView)
```

}

oad a Map Scene
For this first app using the HERE SDK, we want to load one of the default map styles the SDK is shipped with.

In the viewDidLoad() method of our ViewController, we add the following code to load the scene with a map scheme representing a normalDay map render style:

// Completion handler when loading a map scene.
private func onLoadScene(mapError: MapError?) {
guard mapError == nil else {
print("Error: Map scene not loaded, (String(describing: mapError))")
return
}

```
// Configure the map.
let camera = mapView.camera
let distanceInMeters = MapMeasure(kind: .distance, value: 1000 * 10)
camera.lookAt(point: GeoCoordinates(latitude: 52.518043, longitude: 13.405991),
              zoom: distanceInMeters)
```

}

Now, it's time to build and run the app. If all goes well, you should see a HERE map covering the whole area of the screen

For more details, please check the document.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk-explore/4.12.9.0/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html#integrate-the-here-sdk